# How to set query string in url using Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to pass one id in query string in URL and set the path using Angular.js. I am adding my code below.

```
http://localhost/spesh/resetpass?id=2
```

For the above url I need to set path in my routing file which is given below.

```
.state('/resetpass', { 
            url: '/resetpass',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/resetpass.html',
            controller: 'resetpassController'
})
```

I did as per above it is not working as per requirement.

Comment: I think you should be more specific in your question. What's EXACTLY what u are trying to achieve and what u've tried so far. The code u provide is like routing setup. Are you aware that query strings are independent to routes?

Answer (score 0):

this should be better -

```
.state('resetpass', {     
            url: '/resetpass/:id',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/resetpass.html',
            controller: 'resetpassController'
})
```

you can use it like that -

```
$state.go('resetpass', {id: 1} );
```

or

```
<a ui-sref="resetpass({id:1})"></a>
```

you can get the query string within the $stateParams service to do whatever you want with it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.. Change the code as below

```
http://localhost/spesh/resetpass/2       /////CHANGE HERE


.state('/resetpass', { 
            url: '/resetpass/:id',      /////CHANGE HERE
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/resetpass.html',
            controller: 'resetpassController'
})


///to access ID in controller 
var ID = $stateParams.id;
```

Try this if you would want to keep '?'. The below code tells angular that id is expected.

```
url: "/resetpass?id",
```

Comment: i need to keep `?` in the url.any solution?

Answer (score 0):

just change it :

```
.state('/resetpass', { 
            url: '/resetpass?id',
            templateUrl: 'dashboardview/resetpass.html',
            controller: 'resetpassController'
})
```